# Firstname and lastname greyout or hidden Billing details at next checkout like username is hidden

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a woocommerce site designed for max and min quantity and price range pick like donation.

I want something like, if I am registering at checkout, filling username, password, firstname, lastname, email and phone no., I don't want the fields in my next checkout. Same like username and password are hidden in the checkout, if you are already registered.

I just want these fields to be hidden: firstname, lastname and email id if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use filter `woocommerce_checkout_fields`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'checkout_change_fields' );

function checkout_change_fields( $fields ) {

     return $fields;
}
```

more samples https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/